# Searching for max date dynamically

Tags: tableau-api

I have the need to compare a date column with the max(date column) while making a filter selection.

E.g., when I compare [Date] = {max([Date])}, it finds the max/latest date in the entire data and compares. This gives me correct result when the latest month is included in the filter, but fails if I keep all months except the latest.

Is there a way in which the latest date can be searched in the subset of the data (based on filter selection)?

I am working with Redshift database (live connection).

Comment: Try using Context filters. http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_context.html

Comment: @Bernardo tried. Its not working

Comment: can you share a sample workbook?

Comment: I have replicated the workbook using an extract and
 
`iif([Year_Month]=MAKEDATE({[maxYear]},{[maxMonth]},01),[Claim Count],0)`
 
gives me what I am looking for, but in a live connection MAKEDATE is not an available option so I used DATE() as
 
`IIF([NewDate]=DATE("01"+"/"+str([maxMonth])+"/"+str([maxYear])),[Claim Count],0)` 
but this does not return the same results.
 
Your thoughts on this @Bernardo?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but look at the attached. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zdkw9n003rxgvl/170524%20stack%20question.twbx?dl=0
{fixed : max(date)} will reflect only what is in the context filter. is this not what you want?

Comment: It worked. May be that I'd overlooked a certain parameter earlier. Thanks :) @Bernardo

Comment: Cool. I'll add an answer if you could mark it answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look at the attached. https://www.dropbox.com/s/5zdkw9n003rxgvl/170524%20stack%20question.twbx?dl=0
{fixed : max(date)} will reflect only what is in the context filter.